# IDE that can display LaTeX in comments

Tags: c++, ide, latex

Is there any C++ IDE that can display LaTeX formulas in C++ comments as formulas? I envision this as a very handy instrument to document code that implements some math, but in order for it to be useful LaTeX code should be compiled and shown as set of glyphs.

Comment: I've missed this a few times. My fallback is to use words and/or special symbols as much as possible, making it "cross"-IDE. It can be tedious to explain an integral with words though...

Comment: Sounds like a handy Plugin for Eclipse/Netbeans to me

Comment: Doxygen can create documentation with formulas written in latex: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/formulas.html

Comment: @MadScientist I am aware of doxygen, but seeing formulas when you actually browse code is alot more convenient.

Comment: @Vasaka Have you tried CWEB? http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/cweb.html

Comment: My condolences on having your very useful question closed. I wish it wasn't.